# How reset form values using react bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

My goal after clicking the **register** button is:

- Make input fields blank
- Do not show error tooltips

Here is the [**CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactbootstrap-form-yn4io?file=/src/App.js)

I've already tried using **event.target.reset();** however the tooltips are still appearing on the screen.

```
export default function App() {
  const [showSucessAlert, setshowSucessAlert] = useState(false);
  const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);
  const [transitionAlert, setTransitionAlert] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    const form = event.currentTarget;
    event.preventDefault();

    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
      handleClickTransitionAlert();
      setshowSucessAlert(true);
    }
    setValidated(true);
  };

  const handleClickTransitionAlert = () => {
    setTransitionAlert(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTransitionAlert(false);
    }, 1700);
  };

  return (
    <Form noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Form.Group className="position-relative" controlId="validationPassword">
        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
        <InputGroup hasValidation id="validationPassword" />
        <Form.Control
          type="password"
          aria-describedby="validationPassword"
          required
        />
        <Form.Control.Feedback tooltip type="invalid">
          Please enter your Password.
        </Form.Control.Feedback>
      </Form.Group>
      <Alert
        className={`mt-1 p-1 position-fixed ${
          transitionAlert ? "alert-shown" : "alert-hidden"
        }`}
        show={showSucessAlert}
        variant="success"
      >
        Registered user!
      </Alert>
      <Button className="mt-5" variant="primary" type="submit">
        Register
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

[image]

Here is the [**CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactbootstrap-form-yn4io?file=/src/App.js)

*Every help is welcome!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't commonly use uncontrolled components, but I think you could solve this by adding `setValidated(false)` and `event.target.reset()` to the `handleClickTransitionAlert`, like this:

```
  const handleClickTransitionAlert = (event) => {
    setTransitionAlert(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTransitionAlert(false);
      setValidated(false)
      event.target.reset()
    }, 1700);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reseting the validated attribute on Bootsrap Form.
it should look something like this (this is pseudo-code):

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
const FormComponent = () => {
  const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);
  const formRef = useRef(null);

  const handleReset = () => {
    formRef.current.reset();
    setValidated(false);
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
     // Do stuff here
     // On success or error:
    setValidated(true);
    handleReset();
  }

   return(
      <Form ref={formRef}  validated={validated} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        // your form inputs
      </Form>
   );
export default FormComponent;
}
```

Comment: I tried the way you suggested, but the tooltip is still showing

Comment: have you tried conditioning it to the state of the form?

Comment: I didn't have the idea to put it in the state, but I managed to solve it with another answer. thanks for the contribution.